Why do I lose `__doc__` on a parameterized generic?
Issue
The docstring is lost when setting type parameters on a generic.
Minimal example:
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")

class Test(Generic[T]):
    """My docstring"""

assert Test.__doc__ == "My docstring"

This works fine as expected. However, this fails as __doc__ is now None:
assert Test[int].__doc__ == "My docstring"

Expectation
I would expect the docstring to still be the same. Afterall, it's still the "same" class.
Is there something I just don't understand about how Python's typing system making this intendet behavior?
Background
Using parameterized types in FastAPI, I'm losing the description (coming from the docstring) when generating OpenAPI specs.
I can fix this with a decorator, but that leads to more problems in my case with Pydantic's model creation. But that's besides the point. I'd like to understand why this is happening in the first place regardless of non-builtin tools.

I assume it works that way because nobody implemented copying docs to paremtized generics

Parameterising user-defined generic types with type arguments results in instances of typing._GenericAlias, which inherits from typing._BaseGenericAlias.
>>> type(Test[int])
<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>
>>> type(Test[int]).mro()
[<class 'typing._GenericAlias'>, <class 'typing._BaseGenericAlias'>, <class 'typing._Final'>, <class 'object'>]

If you look at the source code, it shows you that attributes are relayed from Test to Test[int] via a __getattr__ defined on _BaseGenericAlias.
This reveals 2 issues preventing __doc__ from being relayed from Test to Test[int]:

Since Test[int] is an instance of typing._GenericAlias, when you're accessing Test[int].__doc__, you are actually accessing typing._GenericAlias.__doc__; since all classes (including typing._GenericAlias) have a .__doc__ = None if no docstring is provided, __getattr__ is never called and you get None. If you add a dummy docstring to your Python standard library's typing.py,
# typing.py
...

class _GenericAlias(_BaseGenericAlias, _root=True):
    """
    HELLO
    """
    ...

you can verify the behaviour:
>>> Test[int].__doc__
'HELLO'


Even if __getattr__ were called, the implementation deliberately avoids relaying dunder attributes (like __doc__):
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
      ...

      # We are careful for copy and pickle.
      # Also for simplicity we don't relay any dunder names
      if '__origin__' in self.__dict__ and not _is_dunder(attr):
          return getattr(self.__origin__, attr)
      raise AttributeError(attr)




I think I was missing the part where Test[int] is not just an instance of a subclass of typing._GenericAlias, but rather it is of type _GenericAlias and does not have Test in its bases. Thanks!
Still, that's a design choice I don't quite understand. Being careful with dunders makes sense, but I would expect __doc__ to be handled, e.g., somewhere in typing._generic_class_getitem.

@ts91 Here's the beginning of a solution: Built-in generics (as opposed to user-defined generics) do allow you to access items like __doc__; see, for example, list[int].__doc__. I'm not sure how much special casing Pydantic has, but if you override __class_getitem__ to return an instance of types.GenericAlias (which is the type of list[int]), you can get __doc__ to appear as you want. Note that creating instances of types.GenericAlias is a part of the public API (as opposed to doing something with typing._GenericAlias).
